# "probable mental disorders" vs "mental disorders"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, difference

> Rates of ***probable mental disorders*** among six- to 16-year-olds increased from 11.6%, or one in nine, in 2017 to 17.4%, or one in six.

Can you please tell me what is the difference between mental disorders and probable mental disorders？Does the latter refer to people who have a risk of developing mental disorders?

Comment: You need to read the referenced report, in which it is explained in more detail on p. 5-6. https://files.digital.nhs.uk/97/B09EF8/mhcyp_2021_rep.pdf

Answer (score 1):

There is no special English idiom here.  When a doctor is investigating the behaviour of a child, they may diagnose a mental disorder.  A survey questionnaire can't certainly diagnose a child. But, based on the results of a questionnaire one may say that a child "probably has a mental disorder". A child with a "mental disorder" certainly has a mental disorder. A child with a "probable mental disorder" probably has a mental disorder.

For more details, see https://files.digital.nhs.uk/97/B09EF8/mhcyp_2021_rep.pdf. It describes how this study determined which children probably had a mental disorder.

> Children and young people with a probable mental disorder
> [The Strengths and Difficulties Questionnaire (SDQ)](https://www.sdqinfo.org/a0.html) was used to
> identify children who may have had problems with aspects of their
> mental health to such an extent that it impacted on their daily lives.
> These include difficulties with their emotions, behaviour, relationships,
> hyperactivity, or concentration. Responses from parents, children and
> young people were used to estimate the likelihood that a child or young
> person might have a mental disorder, this was classified as either
> ‘unlikely’, ‘possible’ or ‘probable’.
>
> Change in SDQ score was also used to classify children and young
> people into whether their mental health in 2021 had deteriorated since
> 2017 (an SDQ score that had increased by three or more), remained
> similar (an SDQ score that was no more than two higher or lower), or
> improved (an SDQ score that had decreased by three or more).
>
> The initial MHCYP 2017 report used a different and more detailed
> diagnostic assessment of mental disorder. Any comparisons between
> 2017, 2020 and 2021 must therefore draw on the results presented in
> this report, which are based on a comparable measure (the SDQ).

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to tell for certain without more context.  However, I would take this sentence as referring to the percentage of children in this age group who *probably* have a mental disorder.  In other words, if there are a hundred kids, and I think that probably ten of them have some kind of disorder, but I don’t know for sure, and might not even know which ones, the rate of probable mental health disorders in that population would be 10%.

One reason social scientists might avoid the phrase “rates of mental disorders” is that the statistic they are using does not directly measure diagnoses of mental disorders, but something else that the paper is using to indirectly estimate the true rate of mental disorders.